# Integration over an area bounded between two curves

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Determine $\int_Axy\space\space d(x,y)$, when $A$ is a closed set, bounded by the curve $y=x-1$, and the parabel $y^2 = 2x+6.$

I believe we only need to know the range, where $A$ is actually bounded by these two curves. I think this will be $-3\leq x \leq 5$. But to be specific, isn't $A\subset Int ( G_h \cap G_g)$, s.t $g(x)=x-1$, and $h(x)=y^2 = 2x+6$? Where $-3\leq x \leq 5$. Can we determine the integral as $$\int_{-3}^5\Bigg(\int_{x-1}^{2x+6}xy\space\space dy\Biggr)dx\space\space?$$

Also, I'm assuming that $(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Did you sketch the region?

Comment: I did. I think the $x$-coordinate is correct. Is there anything else noteworthy about the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Graph]

The curves intersect at $(-1,-2),(5,4)$. For $x\in(-3,-1),y$ goes from $-\sqrt{2x+6}$ to $\sqrt{2x+6}$ but for $-1<x<5,y$ ranges from $x-1$ to $\sqrt{2x+6}$. The required integral is$$\int_{-3}^{-1}\int_{-\sqrt{2x+6}}^\sqrt{2x+6}xy~dy~dx+\int_{-1}^5\int_{x-1}^\sqrt{2x+6}xy~dy~dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing integral into two parts, for simplification, you can set it up as below (integrating over $x$ first between the two curves) -

$\displaystyle \int_{-2}^4\int_{(y^2-6)/2}^{y+1} \, xy \, dx \, dy$

For the region, $-2 \leq y \leq 4$.